# Displaying parameter from API in console

Tags: javascript, api

I'm creating a system which is going to store a bitcoin historical volume data every 24 hours.
I'm using CoinMarketCap API. [API source](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsLatest)
My problem is that I don't understand how I need to specify the parameter to receive the exact bitcoin volume data.

```
    request('GET', 'http://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=API-KEY-HERE')
        .then((r1) => {
            var x1 = JSON.parse(r1.target.responseText);
            console.log(x1.data.quote.BTC.volume_24h); 
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })

    function request(method, url) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open(method, url);
            xhr.onload = resolve;
            xhr.onerror = reject;
            xhr.send();
        });
    }
```

I'm receiving error -

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'BTC' of undefined
    at main.html:10
```

I was trying different combinations and selecting the symbol in endpoint as well.
Where is my mistake and how can I receive a BTC volume only in my console log.

If I add only console.log(x1.data);
I receive this in console - [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwgmK.png)

Comment: What do you have when you put console.log(JSON.stringify(x1.data))

Comment: @djcaesar9114 I edited a main post with attached screenshot of console

Comment: so ```x1.data``` is an array and doesn't have itself the ```quote``` property, probably you should peek an item from the x1.data array and check there

Comment: @asdru I was trying to peek from x1.data let's say max_supply which is in documentation and I receive undefined error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like it should be:

```
console.log(x1.data.find(d => d.symbol === 'BTC').quote.BTC.volume_24h);
```